# Clarification needed on \Device\PhysicalMemory on Windows

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, internals

`\Device\PhysicalMemory` is a section object, that is in Win32 API terms a memory-mapped file. Given its name it could be an MMF *fully* backed by RAM; being a one on one mapping of physical pages.

And that is pretty much my question: does this section object represent nonpaged **physical memory** or the nonpaged **system address space**?

And if it is the former, what about "holes" in physical memory? For example on PAE-enabled systems the physical memory underlying the system address space may be actually "fragmented". What happens if I were to access such holes after mapping a view into that `\Device\PhysicalMemory` section object?

The reason why I am confused is because the `MmMapIoSpace` function takes a `PHYSICAL_ADDRESS PhysicalAddress` parameter and maps that physical address to nonpaged system address space. Also see other memory manager functions like `MmAllocateContiguousMemory`. It seems pretty dangerous to make *actual* physical memory available and pretend it can be accessed in a contiguous fashion.

So clearly there's a mapping that is not necessarily one on one between nonpaged physical memory and nonpaged system address space.

Trying to find the above and a number of related terms in Windows Internals, 6th ed. did not yield any definite answer. Chapter 10 mostly deals with what the WDK documentation calls system address space. Therefore I am asking here.

Please make sure to point to authoritative sources for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Device\PhysicalMemory` is a section object that is backed by physical memory directly. Its view offset represent actual physical addresses. As such it is not contiguous and to use it you must know what ranges are valid.

There's little authoritative information as to how to use \Device\PhysicalMemory as Microsoft assumes that this is something you should not need to do. In fact they made usage of this section as difficult as possible without removing it completely in Windows XP/2003.

As far as MmMapIoSpace: Device drivers that need mapped memory request it via resources during their PnP initialization. Windows assigns ranges of pages of physical memory for exclusive use by device driver and returns CmResourceTypeMemory resources to describe the assigned memory. The device driver then uses MmMapIoSpace to get a kernel mode accessible address. The driver never gives a random address to be mapped. This is described in the [MmMapIoSpace MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554618(v=vs.85).aspx) and other pages linked from this page.

Note that when you use this section or MmMapIoSpace you must be careful that any memory that is mapped uses the same caching semantics as other mapping for the same physical address. If not corruption could occur -- this is especially important if data will be written using the mapping. This is not usually a problem for MmMapIoSpace if used as intended by Microsoft since the owning device driver should know how to map using consistent caching. When using the section you have no way to know if the memory has been mapped in an incompatible manner by some other code.

Driver verifier will indicate failure to use consistent mapping when using the section or MmMapIoSpace and report them as bad mapper failure. In Windows 10 this type of report occurs even without driver verifier making it very difficult to use either method without causing an OS stop.

You do not specify what you are trying to do but I suspect you might be interested in looking at MmCopyMemory with the MM_COPY_MEMORY_PHYSICAL -- see the [MmCopyMemory MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn342884(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks for the details. I was really mostly interested in `\Device\PhysicalMemory` and more out of curiosity than to (ab)use it.Can you give any sources for the claim in the first paragraph?

Comment: I do not have a source to give you.

Comment: By the way, I am not trying to *do* anything, really. I am trying to learn about internals that seem to be undocumented. And I figured typing up a question here is more sensible than starting up IDA and sifting through pages of disassembly :)